# "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" when trying to getLayoutParams of a CardView in a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-layoutparams

I'm trying to set the size of a `CardView` inside of a `DialogFragment`, but I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.support.v7.widget.CardView.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference

This is my code:

```
        CardView cardView;
        onCreate(...){
            cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardViewInDialogFragment);
        }

        private void openDialogFragment() {

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

            BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
            blankFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"blankFragment");

            CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams) cardView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels - 20;
            layoutParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels - 20;
            cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
```

Is it not possible or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:**
The cardView is inside the fragment.

**UPDATE 2:**

When changing the code to bellow:

BlankFragment:

```
public static View view;
pulic void onCreateView(...) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
CardView cardView;
protected void onCreate(...){
    ...

    cardView = (CardView) BlankFragment.view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewInDialogFragment);
    openDialogFragment();
}

private void openDialogFragment() {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
    blankFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"blankFragment");

    CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CardView.LayoutParams) cardView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels - 20;
    layoutParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels - 20;
    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

, I get this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.sim.buttombarnavigationandfragment, PID: 10685
>                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.sim.buttombarnavigationandfragment/com.sim.buttombarnavigationandfragment.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2680)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                               at
>   com.sim.buttombarnavigationandfragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

Comment: cardView instance is null.
Are you sure that id cardViewInDialogFragment is the right id in your inflated layout?
CardView is part of the activity layout or fragment layout?

Comment: `findViewById` is outside of a method, where it will not  work

Comment: @Alex it's the correct id. The CardView is inside the fragment.

Comment: You can't make views static. You **need** to assign the CardView **within** the Fragment... `BlankFragment.view` is still null in your edit

Answer (score 0):

```
public CardView view;
public View onCreateView(...) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

cardView = (CardView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewInDialogFragment);  
openDialogFragment();
return view;
```

}

Comment: I created a `public static View view;` in the fragment class, and in `onCreateView` edited return to this: `return view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);`, and tried to access the view using this: `cardView = (CardView) BlankFragment.view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewInDialogFragment);`, but now it throws this exception: _Unable to start activity ... java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference_

Comment: dont return view directly,first define view and than in the class you can put your cardview line,remove blankfragment.                                                        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);             
      return view;

Comment: just remove blankfragment in the cardview obj declaration

Comment: @jigar-savalia how do i access view if i remove the BlankFragment.? (I'm declaring and assigning view in the fragment class, and accessing it in my MainActivity class.)

Comment: Updated the question.